# Show that Cov(T,T')=Var(T)

Tags: statistics, estimation

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a sample, all with mean $\mu$ and $Var(X_i)<\infty$.  Let $T(X_1,...,X_n)=\sum_{i=1}^na_iX_i$. If T is the UMVUE of $\mu$ and T' is another linear unbiased estimate of $\mu$, then show that

$$Cov(T,T')=Var(T)$$

So I know that $E(T)=E(T')=\mu$ since T and T' are unbiased.

Then I also know that $Cov(T,T')=E(TT')-E(T)E(T')=E(TT')-\mu^2$

Then $Var(T)=E(T^2)-E(T)^2=E(T^2)-\mu^2$

The goal then becomes to show that $E(TT')=E(T^2)$, or to show that $T=T'$.

This is where I get stuck.  I want to use uniqueness of the UMVUE, so I want to show that T' is as UMVUE of $\mu$ giving the desired result.  I assume that since T' is another linear unbiased estimator, it is of the form $\sum_{j=1}^nb_jX_j$.

I suppose one viable approach is to show that $Var(T')\le Var(T)$, where then using that T is the UMVUE we could conclude that T=T' and the problem is done.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: From the little you have written, I doubt any of your Readers can guess "what the problem is asking".  Please make the body of your Question as self-contained as practical, and don't rely solely on the title to pose a problem.  What is $X$?  What is $A$?  Do you know the definition of covariance?

Comment: @hardmath: See the revision history.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think your proposed approach will work - if it did, you would also be proving that when a UMVUE exists, there are no other linear unbiased estimators.

What you can do instead is to say given the UMVUE $T$ and another linear unbiased estimator $T^\prime$, consider the estimator $\lambda T + (1 - \lambda)T^\prime$. You can prove that this is still unbiased, and therfore we have

$\mathrm{Var}(\lambda T + (1 - \lambda) T^\prime) \geq \mathrm{Var}(T)$

for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. This gives a quadratic in $\lambda$ which is non-negative everywhere, and takes the value $0$ when $\lambda = 1$. This means the discriminant of the quadratic must be 0, and following the consequences of this conclusion algebraically will give the result.